# Error C2220 warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong as I am unable to get past the following error (see below)? I've downloaded the ByePG open source from [here](https://github.com/can1357/ByePg). I've successfully compiled and built the ByePgLib project with the already configured settings as set by the author. I've noticed that the two warnings that I'm getting are also present in the build of the ByePgLib project except for the error. I am unable to suppress the error by way of the following project setting for the main project (TestDrv). **Treat Warnings As Errors --> No (/WX-)** in **Visual Studio 2017 Community**

I'm also using .cpp for the main file namely main.cpp in my TestDrv project.

```
Severity Code   Description Project File Line Suppression State

Error   C2220   warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated   TestDrv c:\users\auser\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\xfl\testdrv\testdrv\byepg.h    17  
Warning C4502   'linkage specification' requires use of keyword 'extern' and must precede all other specifiers  TestDrv c:\users\auser\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\xfl\testdrv\testdrv\byepg.h    17  
Warning C4518   '__declspec(dllimport)': storage-class or type specifier(s) unexpected here; ignored    TestDrv c:\users\auser\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\xfl\testdrv\testdrv\byepg.h    17
```

I've included the ByePg.h file here:

```
    /*ByePg.h */
    #pragma once
    #include <ntifs.h>
    
    #define BPG_STATUS_FAILED_TO_HIJACK_HPDT    0xC0013001L
    #define BPG_STATUS_FAILED_TO_RESOLVE_INT    0xC0013002L
    
    typedef LONG( __stdcall* BYE_PG_EX_CALLBACK )( CONTEXT* ContextRecord, EXCEPTION_RECORD* ExceptionRecord );
    
    #ifndef BYEPG_EXPORT  // this is defined in the byepg cpp file
    #ifdef __cplusplus
        #define BYEPG_EXPORT __declspec( dllimport ) extern "C"
    #else
        #define BYEPG_EXPORT __declspec( dllimport )
    #endif
    #endif
    
    BYEPG_EXPORT NTSTATUS ByePgInitialize( BYE_PG_EX_CALLBACK Callback, BOOLEAN Verbose ); <--Warnings/Error
```

Comment: Did you try clean and build?

Comment: Also, are you compiling for C or C++?

Comment: Just fix [the header](https://github.com/can1357/ByePg/blob/cc698e79fc7aa11d3aff79af545e26a93fa104d6/Includes/ByePg.h#L11), extern "C" should be written before the declspec.

Comment: @kiner_shaw thank you. Yes and yes I'm compiling for C++ as I've updated the questions with this details and I've tried "clean solution" and "build solution". As I get the same error again.

Comment: @Hans Passant thank you. I did try what you have suggested and now I'm getting the following linking error. Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_ByePgInitialize referenced in function DriverEntry

Comment: It seems as if you are trying to compile a header file into an object file. Can you confirm this? -- Commonly you cannot do this because there ist no implementation in a header file.

Comment: @thebusybee, yeah seems like this line `Error   C2220   warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated   TestDrv c:\users\auser\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\xfl\testdrv\testdrv\byepg.h    17`

Comment: ***Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_ByePgInitialize referenced in function DriverEntry*** Check your project settings for include paths and library paths. Also check if the required libraries are added properly.

Comment: Did you use library in your program?

Comment: @Yujian Yao yes I added it to Configuration Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies.

Comment: @Hans Passant if you can post your comment as an answer I will accept it. I'm not certain what I did but with the change you had recommended its now building correctly.

Comment: @the busybee No I have not included any function definitions in my code (.h files) but 1 or more of the includes from the ByePgLib do contain function definitions.