# What is the difference between __declspec( dllimport ) extern "C" AND extern "C" __declspec( dllimport )

Tags: c++, c, windows, visual-studio

Would there be any difference between both notations when compiling in a .c file or within a .cpp file ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows & C++: extern & \_\_declspec(dllimport)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288293/windows-c-extern-declspecdllimport)

Comment: Wasn't part of the point in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70768093/error-c2220-warning-treated-as-error-no-object-file-generated question of yours, that the former doesn't compile?

Comment: There's no `extern "C"` in C (only in C++) (and even if it would exist it would do nothing) - so this question only applies to C++.

Comment: @PMF exactly it doesn't link. I get a unresolved external linking error when extern term appears before the __declspec(dllimport). What I was looking for was an explanation of using extern before and after the__declspec(dllimport) and the effect it has on name mangling.

Comment: **I get a unresolved external linking error when extern term appears before the __declspec(dllimport)** Could you provide a minimal, reproducible example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`extern "C"` and `__declspec(dllimport)` are totally orthogonal.

- `extern "C"` means that C linkage should be used for that symbol.  I.e. no C++ name mangling will be applied.  It also limits functions' interfaces to C-compatible things: built-in types, trivial structs, and pointers.  Essentially, it tells the compiler and linker that a symbol should be found in the "C way" rather than the "C++ way".  `extern "C"` is generally used for either calling C functions from C++ code or creating a C-compatible interface to C++ code.
- `__declspec(dllimport)` tells the linker that a symbol will be loaded dynamically at runtime from a DLL.

The two can be combined as well.  A function marked `extern "C" __declspec(dllimport)` will be dynamically linked and use C-style linkage.

Comment: I remember that Petzold's old Programming Windows bible placed all of it in a single macro or typedef, conditionally, depending on if compiled as C or C++, which is probably still a good idea, to hide all of that away.